# Multiply 3 matrix in Keras custom layer

Tags: keras, matrix-multiplication

I would like to create a custom Keras Layer that calculates the product between 2 input matrices and 1 weight matrix (diagonal matrix) : x W y

```
x = Input((8,200)) # (?,8,200)
y = Input((10,200)) # (?,10,200)
W # Weight matrix define with Keras (200,)
```

I want the output matrix that compute xWy with a shape (?, 8, 10)

I try :

```
K.dot(x*W, K.transpose(Y)) # Raise Dimension error
K.dot(x*W, Permute(2,1))(Y)) # (?, 8, ?, 10)
```

Without the first dimension (batch size) I see how to do it, but with it I'm a little lost.

Comment: You wrote that W is a diagonal matrix. Isn't the shape of W `(200,200)` then, instead of `(200,)`?

Comment: I wanted to use a diagonal matrix W (200,200) with weights only on the diagonal, the rest at 0 and not trainable, but the easiest way is to use a vector W (200,) and do x*W (8,200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `K.batch_dot`, which is made for this purpose.

```
 K.batch_dot(x*W, K.permute_dimensions(y, (0,2,1)), axes=[2, 1]) # (?, 8, 10)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.... I had missed it in the doc. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the axis along which to take the dot product in a Keras Dot layer. The following code shows how to multiply your inputs `x` and `y`. If you want to add a weight matrix `W` you can do that in a similar way (by first multiplying `x` and `W`).

```
x = Input((8,200)) # (?,8,200)
y = Input((10,200)) # (?,10,200)
output = keras.layers.Dot(axes=-1)([x, y]) # (?,8,10)
```